# What does "::function()" mean in cpp?

Tags: c++

In source file, for example we have class A.

```
A::b() {
  ::c();
}
```

what does "::c()" mean?

Answer (score 6):

It means «call the `c()` function from the global namespace»; typically used when there's a class method with the same name, that would be called if `::` wasn't specified.

Often seen in C-libraries wrapper classes, when wrapper methods have the same name as the "original" C functions.

Notice that it's just a special case of the namespace resolution operator that you often see used like `namespace::name` (e.g. `std::cout`); to specify that you want a name from the global namespace you just omit the `namespace` part.

Comment: Then, basically it'll call "e.g. void c() {}" which does not belong to any class?

Comment: @hytgbn: not only `c` must not belong to any class, but must not be in any namespace (it must be in the global namespace).